# AnkhSVN doesn't show folder's status icon in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

My AnkhSVN doesn't show folder's status icon in Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

How to let it icon show on folder ?

Answer (score 0):

AnkhSVN does not support showing status for folders:
[image: AnkhSVNDoesNotSupportFolderStatus]

[VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/), however, supports showing folder status. Cumulative traffic-light status is displayed for physical folders, filters (in C++ projects) and for solution folders.

[image]